AWS Limit Backend ALB allow Inbound from Frontend ALB
Three tier app
Frontend, backend and Database
Frontend - Ec2 is in private subnet and attached to ALB in Public subnet with 0.0.0.0
Backend One with Public ALB - Ec2 in private subnet and attached to public facing ALB in Public subnet with Inbound only from Frontend ALB and frontend EC2 Security group on all ports (ideally I need only 443)
Backend Two with Internal ALB - Ec2 in private subnet and attached to internal ALB in private subnet with Inbound only from Frontend ALB and frontend EC2 Security group on all ports (ideally I need only 443)
Issue:

When The backend security group is limited inbound with traffic only from frontend ALB then, Frontend portal is getting 504 error (resource not found) basically it doesn't connect
if I allow 0.0.0.0 on Port 443 of Backend load balancer then, Frontend is able to connect with backend and process all requests.

If I try to use internal load balancer it doesnt work as that has HTTP URL and which can't be used by HTTPS frontend


Issue: Why after limiting the rules of Backend ALB it doesn't work
What I tried:

Giving access to all ports from frontend ALB SG and Frontend EC2 SG
Outbound of backend ALB open to all on all ports
Creating a internal load balancer for backend and accessing that with HTTPS frontend (getting mixed content warning as HTTPS do not work with HTTP)

